# Remove all instances from a list

Tags: python, list

I'm trying to remove all instances of words from a list. I searched and pretty much all the answers are similar to my code below but I can't get it to work. The list simply returns the same list without removing any words. For the print function at the very end if I enter a word like "and" manually instead of the parameter it works so I assume it has something to do with the "remove_words" list.

I'm using vscode and imported a text file with a few paragraphs in them.

```
myFile = open("mytext.txt")

remove_words = ["and", "a", "to", "the", "if", "is", "it", "of"]

mylist = myFile.read().lower()
newlist = mylist.split(" ")

def remove_items(thelist, item):
    final_list = [i for i in thelist if i != item]
    return final_list

print(remove_items(newlist, remove_words))
```

Comment: In your own words: when the list comprehension `[i for i in thelist if i != item]` runs, what are you expecting the value of `item` to be? What do you expect `i` to look like, at any given point? Does comparing `i != item` make sense to you, considering that? What is the actual logic you want, between the value that `i` has and the value that `item` has?

Comment: You likely want to use `if not i in item`

Comment: The value of item should be "remove_words" variable.I was under the impression that "!=" and "not in" were the same. But after I used "if not in" instead of "!=" it worked...I'll need to go back and review these. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

item is a list so just replace the comprehension code as below.

```
def remove_items(thelist, item):
    final_list = [i for i in thelist if not i in item]
    return final_list
```

Answer (score 0):

You are passing `remove_words` as the `item` parameter, meaning that you are passing a list and not a word

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is that `remove_words` is a list of strings, while `remove_items` expects one string. If you want to not have to change `remove_items`, you would have to pass each item in `remove_words` to it separately:

```
for word in remove_words:
    newlist = remove_items(newlist, word)
print(newlist)
```

As others pointed out and given examples of, though, if you changed `remove_items`, you could have it accept a list of words to remove, thus simplifying your code.

Answer (score 0):

instead of using "!=" try "not in". Hope that works.

Answer (score 0):

As other answers mention, you pass the list of items rather than a single item to be removed. Try this instead:

```
def remove_items(thelist, items):
    final_list = [i for i in thelist if i not in items]
    return final_list
```

Answer (score 0):

It is best to use `with open` when handling files.

Use `filter` to filter out the unwanted words:

```
remove_words = ["and", "a", "to", "the", "if", "is", "it", "of"]

with open("mytext.txt") as myFile:
    mylist = myFile.read().lower()
    newlist = mylist.split(" ")

def remove_items(thelist, item):
    return list(filter(lambda a: a not in item, thelist))

print(remove_items(newlist, remove_words))
```